# How can I go back to previous version

Tags: uninstall, 15.10

I recently upgraded to Lubuntu 15.10, and I'm having serious problems with my display. At this point, the first thing I want to do is go back to my previous version. Is there a good way to do that other than creating and using a new installation disk?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, ***no***. Due to the way upgrades work, it is **VERY** difficult for you to do a clean down-grade while keeping all of your files, apps, and preferences. The simplest, cleanest solution here is to back up all of your import files and do a clean re-install of your preferred version.

I recently(AKA 15 minutes ago) went through the same process. You are able to keep some system config files safe through this process, such as `etc/fstab`, by using `sudo mv` or `sudo cp` to transfer them onto external storage and then move them back when the reinstall is finished. That is what I did.